How can I change the color of MUI Datagrid Column Dropdown Radio Buttons?
I am trying to change the primary color used in the accents of the MUI Datagrid to a specific green color, however I am having difficulty accessing the css class of the dropdown menu's radio buttons as well as the "HIDE ALL" and "SHOW ALL" buttons within that dropdown through the sx attribute.
How can I target them correctly?
MUI Datagrid Column Dropdown
<DataGrid
                        density="compact"
                        columns={cols}
                        rows={searchResData}
                        className="mx-auto min-h-[300px] bg-white"
                        initialState={{
                            pagination: { paginationModel: { pageSize: 10 } },
                            columns: {
                                columnVisibilityModel: {},
                            },
                        }}
                        pageSizeOptions={[5, 10, 15, 20]}
                        autoHeight
                        slots={{
                            toolbar: GridToolbar,
                            noRowsOverlay: () => noRowsOverlay(keyword as string),
                            noResultsOverlay: () => noResultsOverlay(),
                        }}
                        style={{ minWidth: "80%" }}
                        loading={loading}
                        sx={{
                            
                            "& .MuiSwitch-switchBase.Mui-checked": {
                                backgroundColor: bpi_light_green,
                            },
                            "& .MuiSwitch-switchBase.Mui-checked + .MuiSwitch-track": {
                                backgroundColor: bpi_light_green,
                            },
                            "& .MuiButtonBase-root": {
                                color: bpi_light_green, // Changes the color of the buttons
                            },
                        }}
                    />

I've already tried taking the css class from the developer tools but that doesn't seem to be working for me

What mui grid version are you using? Here is a working example for latest version (7) https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rsgyfy-qcjc78?file=Demo.tsx

@MoshFeu I am using the Community version shown here: https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/
For the sake of me not having to ask this type of question again, would you mind explaining your process for identifying the correct CSS classes to target? Thank you so much for your help and understanding. I apologize for the delay in response

I find the class names in the component's api page (scroll down to the api section, click on the DataGrid link and scroll to the section called CSS classes) and sorry for the late reply :)
